# Extjs 7 modern combobox multiselect bug

Tags: extjs

I want to make a email selector field like Gmail. I use a combox with remote store and multiSelect : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cnn

When i enter few characters, the store load, i get a dropdown list and my inputted text is transformed in a chip :(

How can i prevent chip creation on store loading ? Or how can i do to reproduice Gmail email (to, cc, bcc) component with another extjs component ? (in extjs 4, i used a tagfield and it work perfectly)

[Here is a capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgC7S.gif)

Comment: Did you modified your fiddle? I cannot reproduce the bug, but a bug in the fiddle code itself, when I select multiple mail addresses. The chip is only created when I select an entry from the picker.

Comment: Yes, a sencha developer is working on my fiddle.  Here is a new fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cnn

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in 7.5.1

In 7.5.0 it's even worse.
And in 7.4 and below your error occurs.